# Unexpected UART communication behavior on Basys 2 FPGA using USB-to-UART converter

Tags: electrical, computer

I am facing an issue with UART communication on a Basys 2 FPGA board (design in Verilog). My board doesn't have a built-in UART, so I'm utilizing a USB-to-UART converter for the purpose.

In my constraint file, I have designated two PMOD pins on the FPGA: one as an input (Rx) and the other as an output (Tx). My Verilog module simply assigns Tx = Rx for echoing the received characters.

Now, when I test this setup using Teraterm, I'm seeing the expected behavior. The received characters are indeed being echoed back. However, something unusual is happening. When I connect the USB-to-UART converter Rx and Tx pins to other pins on the FPGA (ones that aren't specified in my constraints file), I still observe the same echoing behavior. How do I fix it?

Comment: maybe the FPGA is not working, and teraterm is doing local echo